# How to format each line in a textbox in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Can I loop through a Textbox for each line entered and format it? For example if the user entered:

```
Text1
Text2
```

I would like to output it as in a single line.

> 'Text1','Text2'

Also would be awesome if you can get the last comma to not display.

Comment: Bonus points? Bounty award? ;)

Comment: You want it with `'` apostrophe right?

Comment: Just remove wrap text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you really need

- Add a textbox to your sheet
- Add this code on TextBox1_Change() event

  ```
  Dim mystr      

  mystr = Split(Sheet1.TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
  Sheet1.Range("A1") = "'" & Join(mystr, "','") & "'"
  ```
- Right click to textbox and enable multiline option
- Control + Enter to change line inside textbox

And you have the result that you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works wonderfully. I had it outputting in a test box instead of the sheet so I just replaced Sheet.Range("A1") with Textbox2.Text